# SQL query is there do and don't WHERE , AND

Tags: php, sql

I have a request that has 4 conditions:

```
$query = "
SELECT ROW,col
FROM mytable
WHERE ROW = $num
  AND col = '$col'
  AND loc = '80'
  AND user_id = $_SESSION[id]
";
```

Should I only have the first condition then parse the data with to apply the 2 other AND statement.

I'm looking for the fastest way to retrieve and parse the data.

Comment: never do filtering in client-side logic UNLESS you know you're just going to have to re-fetch "unwanted" data again anyways. It's almost always better to have the database do all of the filtering for you, otherwise you have to pull data off disk, format it for the wire, sent it on the wire, parse it in client-side data structures, blah blah blah. if you don't need to some data, don't make the DB fetch it.

Comment: When interpolating array items you should do it properly: `{$_SESSION['id']}` instead of `$_SESSION[id]`. You may also want to look at the [HEREDOC syntax](http://php.net/heredoc); it lends itself well to SQL queries.

Comment: Ok so my request is optimal as is. I don't have to change everything. I will set some indexes to help sql retreive the data but later in my project, right now i'm still changing the database design.

Comment: $_SESSION weird that it was working. I change the syntax thank you i'm neewb

Answer (score 1):

There is technically nothing wrong with the methodology, other than the fact that you may want to filter your data (or better yet, use prepared statements).

Also, what will be crucial is whether or not you have a proper index on the columns which are named in your conditions. That way, your database engine doesn't have to scan the whole table, instead it can use an index (performance benefit will be very noticeable with a bigger table).

Comment: I will have to find good tutorial or book about indexing. I know nothing about it and i'm sure I should. Neewb

Answer (score 1):

As in first comment - always use DB to filter data (mind using indexes for faster searching) It's good to use EXPLAIN on certain queries to check if they can be optimised. Try to use parameterized queries, PDO?